# Do violets die in closed space?

Tags: flowers, african-violets

I will soon be making florariums (a garden in the bottle). I wish to include violets, but I've heard that violets will die in an enclosed space. Does anyone know why this happens? Is it lack of oxygen, or CO2, or moisture control issues?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't think they make good subjects for a terrarium for the following, various reasons:- they like very bright light (which they may not get inside something), there's a need to nip off side shoots on mature plants to encourage flowering, (which will be difficult/impossible), and although they like high humidity, they do have a tendency to develop mould on the flowers and sometimes the leaves, and are susceptible to crown rot caused by botrytis, a condition which will thrive in a closed, humid environment. They also prefer to be slightly pot bound, and that'd be difficult to achieve too. Even on an open windowsill, a plant which has a leaf touching the glass may succumb to disease, never mind inside a glass container. Note: this information pertains to Saintpaulia, or African violet.

Answer (score 3):

African violets (saintpaulia species, not viola species) often do well in terrariums, especially the minis and micro-minis.  They flower well, and come in many different colors.  You might consider substituting these for the violets you were hoping to use.